# Signals in django. Profile does not exist

Tags: python, django, model, profile

For each user I create, I also create a profile with post_save signals. With that profile you can follow users using the many to many 'followers' field. When I press addfollower or removefollower I get an error that highlights : profile = Profile.objects.get(pk = pk) as the wrong line. As this error only occurs with the profiles that I create through signals, it seems to me that the problem is when I am creating the profile automatically.

My signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver (post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user = instance)
        profile.followers.add('1')
```

my methods:

```
class AddFollower(ListView):
    def post(self, request, pk , *args, **kwargs ):
        print('usuario aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaagregado')
        profile = Profile.objects.get(pk = pk)
        profile.followers.add(self.request.user)
        
        return redirect('profile', username = profile.user.username)

class RemoveFollower(ListView):

    def post(self, request, pk , *args, **kwargs ):
        print(f'reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeemovingFollower2{request.user}')
        profile = Profile.objects.get(pk = pk)
        profile.followers.remove(self.request.user)

   
        return redirect('profile', username = profile.user.username)
```

my profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_img = models.ImageField(default='user.png')
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True, related_name='followers')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} profile'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a string instead of a user instance to the many-to-many field of your profile, so your profile is not being created.

This line in your signals.py

```
profile.followers.add('1')
```

should be

```
profile.followers.add(instance)
```

but that would make a user follow himself, I don't know if that is the functionality you want, if not you should probably remove it from the signals

Comment: Thanks. Now it follows itself when I create it, but it still gives me the same error (Exception Value:
Profile matching query does not exist). It even gave me the error before filling in the many to many field. I just wanted there to be something in followers to see if it stopped giving the error but the error is anyway

Comment: You probably need to clear your database and re-register users

Comment: @ Ogieleguea Hillary  
Thank you! I would like to solve it without cleaning the database. But I did and that and the command: manage.py migrate --run-syncdb have been the solution to this problem